# Get first item from comma delimited object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have an object rowObject passed into a javascript function. When I inspect it by putting it into an alert I see something like:

```
435,345,345345,56456
```

What I want to achieve is to get the first integer ie. 435 from the list.

I know how to do this in server side code but client side code.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `rowObject[0]`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your `rowObject` is a string, you can use `.split()` to split the comma delimited list. At this point you can access the array of items by index and get the first element.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

An Example

```
var rowObject = "435,345,345345,56456";
var splitRowObject = rowObject.split(',');
if(splitRowObject.length > 0)
    alert(splitRowObject[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`alert()` is calling objects `toString()` method, so you don't know the structure of the object. It is a good idea to use `console.log` instead for logging objects as in modern browsers it will allow you to explore structure of the object in the console window.

One of the solutions you can do without knowing the structure is:

```
var firstInteger = +rowObject.toString().split(',')[0] // 435
```

That works if `rowObject` is string, array or everything else :).

EDIT: Putting `+` before the string will try to convert it to a number.

Comment: why do you try to convert it to a number?

Comment: @haynar because AnonyMouse may need it as an integer (was not specific about that) and for some readers this can be a new trick

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the alert shows `435,345,345345,56456` doesn't mean that the object is string, it could be `Object` and `Array` as well as their toString method implemented to display it in such way. For example the native array is also looks like that when alerting or converting to string, so you need to call toString method at first then split it by comma:

```
var firstInt = rowObject.toString().split(',')[0];
```